# Summarizing data in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif, formulas

Im trying to summarise some data that i have in a spreadsheet. See below for an extract. 
Basically, im trying to count how many "Yes"&"N/A" there are for each month and also how many "No" there are for each month and display it in the form of a chart.

I've managed to do it as an overall but cant seem to break it down per month.

Any help would be appreciated. thanks!

[Overall Performance Chart and Counts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KSyw.jpg)

[Larger Extract of Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2eaQ.jpg)

Comment: How would you imagine breaking it down per months ? You can use function sumifs to use conditioning while summarizing

Comment: so in total for Q1, there are 5 "Yes/N/A" and 1 "No", but that has 4 rows for november and 1 for december. I want to show how many "Yes/N/A" and "No" for all the rows in november, december and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your setup looks like, but this works for me.

In A1:B14
January Yes
January Yes
January Yes
February    Yes
March   Yes
April   No
May No
June    No
July    No
August  Yes
September   Yes
October Yes
November    Yes
December    Yes

In F1:F12
January
February
March
April
May
June
July
August
September
October
November
December

G1 = Yes
H1 = No

I1 = =SUMPRODUCT((A:A=F1)*(B:B=$G$1))
J1 = =SUMPRODUCT((A:A=F1)*(B:B=$H$1))

Fill down.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely clear on how your data are structured - it would have helped to see more than one row - but I think you're looking for `countifs`. It's just like `countif`, except you can define multiple criteria for it to use when counting. If you construct a table that captures all of your conditions (i.e. each month and all of the possible answers), then you can write a `countifs` statement to count the number of occurrences of each combination in your data.

[Example on made-up data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfJUL.png)

In my example, the formula in the top left cell of the summary table is `=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$18,$D5,$B$2:$B$18,E$4)`, which you can drag to the rest of the table.

Comment: Yeah i was thinking that but wasnt sure on how to use it correctly. Ive uploaded a better extract of my data. thanks!

Comment: I'm unclear as to how the "Q"s play into what you're trying to do (are they questions, quarters?) but it seems like 'countifs' is your answer here.